# SOQL query to retrieve last row of table

Tags: database, salesforce, soql

What is the SOQL query to retrieve last row of table?

Comment: What did you try? Why did you tag this with salesforce?

Comment: what do you mean by "last row" ?

Comment: nothing. I come from school of ORM so I have minimum experience in writing sql query.

Comment: last record based on what? sql rows have no reliable inherent order. e.g. do you want "highest id", or "latest timestamp", or what?

Comment: @Oded it's tagged with SalesForce because SOQL = Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL). This is for querying a salesforce database..

Comment: This should not be tagged SQL or database; it should be SOQL instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SOQL is a bit different than SQL. `TOP 1` is not valid in SOQL (Salesforce Object Query Language), you would need to use `LIMIT 1`.

Check the documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm

You could try this, too:
`SELECT Id From ObjectName__c ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thinking about it more, instead of ID you could use `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC` as well. That may provide better results.

Comment: The whole idea about retrieving record is. I want to display updated_at date for my custom object. I thought maybe I will take date of Last Create row and display it as updated date. Do you have better option for this?

Comment: There's a default field Salesforce automatically updates every time a record is modified called `LastModifiedDate`. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a concept of last in databases. I think a table is a set of records, and  as a result the records are unique (hello primary key!) and there is no CONSISTENT ordering like an array (or a salesforce list)

With that warning, There's a better way to do this. do a count() to get the number of records on the object. You'd do it like this:
rn =  SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Account

then you want that nth record. to select it you use:
SELECT * 
FROM Account
Where rn = ..... <- how to indicate the nth row, i'm not sure how to do in soql.